# How to logout from shibboleth

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, shibboleth

Im using shibboleth services inorder to acheive the following

1. User tries to access the secured resource in https://sp.dev.myserver.com/secure/
2. redirects to WAYF
3. selects idp and redirects to IDP and authenticated against School's LDAP 
   username:myuser@gmail.com
   password:test
4. redirects to "https://sp.dev.myserver.com/secure/" and the atttributes are made  available in the SP's Session.

   PHP Test

   ```
       <?php 
           echo '<p>Hello User</p>'; 
       ?> 

       <?php 
           echo "Given Name:  " . $_SERVER["givenName"] . ".<br>";
           echo "Email     :  " . $_SERVER["mail"] . ".";
     ?> 
   <a href="https://sp.dev.myserver.com/Shibboleth.sso/Logout">Logout ME</a>
      </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. I could show the details of the authenticated user in this php page.
6. Now i have added a hyper link to perform Sign Out and added the log out url in it
7. Now when i hit the logout button it redirects to url and shows the below

I closed the browser and tried accessing https://sp.dev.myserver.com/secure but the session was not destroyed and it showed the page with the details from the previous login.

How do i achieve a proper sign out.Can some body help me to fix this ?

PS:Please let me know if i want to add more info. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time, whenever a user closed their browser, all the session cookies were deleted. And then browser developers decided it would be "helpful" to keep the session cookies after closing the browser. See the [background information here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76813/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-for-forcing-logout-on-browser-quit).

I'm *guessing* that your browser is not set in such a way as to clean out session cookies when close your browser. Use the background information to change your settings and try testing again.

Since this busted the "close browser to log out" instruction for many SAML federations (as i believe you have experienced), groups that originally didn't believe in implementing SLO (Single Log Out) now  support SLO. If the school's IDP has a SLO endpoint, you can implement log out against that.  See [Section 4.4 for the Single Log Out spec (PDF)](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf). Note the endpoint will be identified in the IDPs metadata as the SingleLogoutService.

Comment: Currently i have constructed a logout url from the service provider's session information . https://sp.dev.myserver.com/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https://idp.dev.myserver.com/idp/profile/Logout

Comment: Have you verified that your browser is not persisting session cookies across a session?

Comment: Im using that for the time being, haven't test thoroughly though.But each time when i logout the session clears and asks me to authenticate.Before it wasnt showing the login screen.Its ok now.

Comment: @playmaker420 Can you properly explain how did you solve the issue?

Comment: @Henry Mate to be frank its almost 5years ago and totally out of touch with Shibboleth.Can you check my previous comment and try?

Comment: @playmaker420 It's okay mate, somehow it was solved when I used ProxyPass to point the /secure path to our deployed Tomcat Server.