# Shibboleth SP logout does not redirect to my correct server URL

Tags: azure, iis, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

I have recently configured `Shibboleth Service Provider` for my IIS web server and Microsoft Azure. The authentication works like a charm but I do have some problems getting Azure or Shibboleth to redirect to my correct local logout page.

To be honest then I am not 100% sure how the logout mechanism works but from my web page I am calling this logout:

`https://my.webserver.xyz/Shibboleth.sso/Logout`

This will in fact log me off from Azure on my application but my problem is that it will show this standard Shibboleth logout page after logoff:

```
Local Logout
Status of Local Logout: Logout completed successfully.
You MUST close your browser to complete the logout process.
```

But I want it to redirect to `https://my.webserver.xyz/loggedout/` instead of this standard information.
After some more troubleshooting I found that I could add an URL `return` parameter like this:

`https://my.webserver.xyz/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https://my.webserver.xyz/loggedout/`

But this gives the exact same local HTML file from Shibboleth.

I know that I can change the local Shibboleth `/etc/localLogout.html` file to redirect to my logout URL:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://my.webserver.xyz/loggedout/'" />
</head>
</html>
```

But this seems to be a bad and cumbersome method so surely I am missing out some details here.
I am using [Shibboleth][2] v3.1.0.1 with IIS and PHP if this is relevant.

Can anyone point me in a direction on how I can navigate directly to my logout page?

Comment: Please refer to this article, which deeply described this issue.
https://www.oit.uci.edu/idm/shibboleth/slo/
In addition, is this link helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442789/how-to-logout-from-shibboleth

Comment: Sorry, but there was no help in these. My system does logout correctly but my problem is that the logout redirection is wrong - that it should redirect to another URL after logut instead of to the standard one provided by Shibboleth.

Comment: Can you maybe post your update as an answer, so it receives (Azure related) upvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer the question myself as there have been no other solutions propossed and this seems to work for me.

I have found the problem with this as it seemed to be myself being too impatient ;-) I think I may have tested the logout functionality too soon after the configuration changes in Azure as Azure needs some time before the changes get effectuated.

I have now found out that when I have this `Logout URL` configured in Azure `https://my.webserver.xyz/Shibboleth.sso/Logout` then it redirects me back to the above standard Shibboleth `/etc/localLogout.html` logout page.

When I configure the Azure `Logout URL` to be `https://my.webserver.xyz/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https://my.webserver.xyz/loggedout/` then it actually will redirect directly back to this page from Azure.

It is not required to redirect back to the same URL as the one configured in Azure - you can just have a link on your web page like this `https://my.webserver.xyz/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=https://my.webserver.xyz/test-123/` and it will redirect back to this after logout.

Morale here - be a little more patient and allow for some Azure synchronization time before rushing out and doing a lot of configuration changes :-)